# Route Application Data to Tor Hidden Service

Tags: networking, proxy, routing, tor, socks5

I've purchased a file sharing sharing utility that connects to a server using the server's hostname and/or IP (intentionally not FTP). In order to make the system as secure as possible, I decided to run the server through a Tor hidden service.

The problem is that the client does not support `.onion` hostnames, so I was wondering if there's any way to route the application traffic to the hidden service. This must be all in Windows by the way.

What I thought so far:

1. On the client, set the server host to the `.onion` address on port
   `A`.
2. Add an entry to the hosts file to have the `.onion` address point to
   `127.0.0.1`.
3. Have some sort of software listen to `127.0.0.1` on port
   `A` and route the incoming traffic (using the SOCKS5 proxy provided
   by Tor) to the real `.onion` address on port `B`.
4. On the server, set up the server instance on port `C`
   and configure a tor hidden service to route incoming traffic from the
   `.onion` address on port  `B` to `127.0.0.1` on port `C`.

I'm stuck at step 3, I can't seem to find something that does this.

Comment: Tor itself knows how to route `.onion` links; can you not simply bind its proxy to port A on localhost and have it handle the traffic?

Comment: You could use proxifier to force your application to be routed through the TOR SOCKS proxy. It allows per-app settings so that might work.

Comment: @AaronMiller How would running the Tor SOCKS5 proxy on 127.0.0.1:A help?

Comment: I've solved the problem using `socat`, but I'm open to better alternatives.